# Convert hours:minutes:seconds into total minutes in excel

Tags: excel

How can I convert `hours:minutes:seconds` into total minutes in Excel?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[image]

Just use the formula

> =A8*60*24

Comment: can you be more specific! What is the Output? Can you post a Picture?

Comment: when i convert 08:49:05 to minutes using the formula =A8*60*24,  what i getting is 02:00:00.

Comment: you need to format the other cell to number.

Answer (score 13):

Just use the formula

```
120 = (HOUR(A8)*3600+MINUTE(A8)*60+SECOND(A8))/60
```

Comment: Also works in Google Spreadsheet

Answer (score 12):

The only way is to use a formula or to format cells. The method i will use will be the following:
Add another column next to these values.
Then use the following formula:

```
=HOUR(A1)*60+MINUTE(A1)+SECOND(A1)/60
```

[image]